# Getting every single public transport stop coordinates

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, openstreetmap

I want to get a list of public transport stops in my town to be able to extract for example tram stops with their coordinates. I have already found some documentation on geocoding in [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and [open street map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), but these two can only give some info when supplied with a concrete name. Any response is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of OpenStreetMap take a look at the [public transport tagging scheme](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Public_transport) and get comfortable with using the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) or the beginner friendly interface [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) (take a look at its nice [wizard](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Wizard)).

For tram stops the [tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) [railway=tram_stop](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:railway%3Dtram_stop) is used. Buses in contrast are tagged with [highway=bus_stop](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dbus_stop). Unfortunately there is [another more complex public transport tagging scheme](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Proposed_features/Public_Transport) used in parallel, so some stops might follow this other approach instead and you will have to look for those tags, too.

I created an [example query for tram and bus stops in Dresden](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/5fU) for you. The data can be exported in various formats, including XML, GeoJSON, GPX and KML.

Comment: The overpass turbo service is a gem. Just what I needed.